# Firebase Auth Anonymous Sign in possible error cases

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, error-handling, firebase-authentication

When signing in an anonymous user with firebase on Android, the `signInAnonymously` method currently returns a Task. This Task holds an AuthResult, which can be used to check if the user authentication was successful via the  `.isSuccessful` method. However, the Firebase docs also handle the error case when the authentication was not successful, see [example firebase auth repo](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/14cfefcaf00f9aae6f613281f46000d15f9047be/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/kotlin/AnonymousAuthActivity.kt#L63-L75). Now I wonder what could be possible errors for an unsuccessful login when using the `signInAnonymously` method?

Already checked some docs but couldn´t find any pieces of information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This Task holds an AuthResult, which can be used to check if the user authentication was successful via the .isSuccessful method.

It's always recommended to check if the Task is not successful instead of assuming that everything works fine.

> Now I wonder what could be possible errors for an unsuccessful login when using the signInAnonymously method?

A common Exception for an unsuccessful sign-in might have the following message:

> This operation is restricted to administrators only.

This [FirebaseAuthException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException) occurs when you forgot to enable Anonymous Authentication in the Firebase Console.